# Angular 8 - how to invoke global method?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I use Angular 8 and I try to use svg icons that I've downloaded (.js library).

In my `.angular.json` file I added:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/csspatternlibrary3/js/site-utils.js",
    "node_modules/csspatternlibrary3/js/svg-cache.js",
    "node_modules/csspatternlibrary3/js/svg-url.js"
]
```

and

```
"assets": [
    {
        "glob": "**/favicon.ico",
        "input": "./src",
        "output": "./assets"
    },
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    {
        "input": "/node_modules/csspatternlibrary3/svg/",
        "glob": "**/*latest.svg",
        "output": "./svg"
    },
...
]
```

And to be able to use svg icons the method `brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();` has to be invoked... The question is if I should somewhere invoke sth like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();
  });
</script>???
```

When I invoke `brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();` in the console after starting my app then I see my newly added SVG icons but I want to invoke this method when my app is loading...

**UPDATE**

After your recommendations:

1. I added:

   // add this to app.module.ts, providers:
   {
   provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: init,
   }

in my app.module.ts:
],

```
providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: RequestInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ResponseInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: init,
    },
    AppService,
    LocalDataService,
    ValidationService,
```

2. Added:

   // declare above the ngModule declaration or its own file..
   export function init() {
   brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();
   }

in my home.component file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataCenterService} from '@data-center/data-center.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
// import * as brandcpl from '../../../assets/js/svg-url.js';

export function init() {
  (window as any).brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  hasPermissionToReview$: Observable<boolean>;
```

And I now I get the following errors:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/SauceLabs' in 'C:\Users\me\Documents\intellij_workspace\comp\edp-app\node_modules\sauce
    labs'
    ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\me\Documents\intellij_workspace\comp\edp-app\node_modules\protractor\
    built'
    ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/taskRunner.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\me\Documents\intellij_workspace\comp\edp-app\node_modules\protractor\
    built'
    ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js
...
...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did u try adding 

brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();

To ngOnInit() { .. } of appComponent?

Comment: Yes, I get the error HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: _assets_js_site_utils_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.initializeAllSvgIcons is not a function
    at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.ngOnInit but invoking brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons() on the browser console works

Answer (score 0):

Alright, u can try app initializer maybe.

```
// declare above the ngModule declaration or its own file..
export function init() {
   brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();
}

// add this to app.module.ts, providers:
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: init,
}
```

Comment: You will most like need `(window as any).brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcon()` - the accessor `brandcpl` will otherwise not be accepted as it is not defined in `window` interface (for obvious reasons).

Comment: @Jelle Bruisten - where should I add these lines of code (export function init() {
   brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();
})? IN my app.module.ts? Then brandcpl variable is not recognizable

Comment: Hmm as a recap - where should I invoke brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();? IN my component where SVG icons are used -> export function init() {
  window.brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DataCenterModule,
    ReviewModule,
  ],
})
export class HomeModule {
}  but then brandcpl is not recognized...

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons(); in my home.component.ts where I use SVG icons doesn't work (icons are not visible)

Comment: @pascalpuetz you're right! I added (window as any).brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcon() in my home.component.ts in ngOnInit hook and it works!

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong... Icons are not visible but when after loading the whole page I invoke  brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons() on the browser's console and the the icons will appear because the invoked method just changes my <svg> tags properly, then maybe I should call my method in the following hook: ngAfterViewInit() {
    (window as any).brandcpl.initializeAllSvgIcons();
  }??? CUurrently when I invoke my method in ngOnInit then locally icons are visible, but on dev environment (on AWS) - NOT.